# Implement QoS in Tigase

Tags: xmpp, tigase

**QoS** is a way to guarantee message delivery in Tigase/XMPP. Can anyone please let me know if there is any **XEP** available for it Or any standard which can help me in guaranteed message delivery.

What if i maintain a queue of every outgoing packet in XMPP and later on when i receiver delivery report from client. At that time i can cross check messages which are not delivered.

I am using Tigase Please if you guide me about which is the best place for **queueing** and **cross checking** of delivery report with messages

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is not simple answer to your question. It mostly depends what QoS means for you and what you need. I suggest you read this forums topic where your question is discussed and I think a good explanation is provided:
https://projects.tigase.org/boards/4/topics/313

In short, there are quite a few mechanism in Tigase for different kinds of QoS requirements so you have to know which one to use.